# Cannot get an Oracle Linux 6.4 virtual machine guest OS connected to network. Cannot access it from the host machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, oracle-linux

I have a web server running on Oracle Linux 6.4 on VirtualBox. It has an `eth1` address of `10.0.2.15`. I want to be able to run a web server from this virtual machine, but I can’t access the virtual machine from my host. The guest OS also can’t reach the Internet; I can’t ping Google.

Currently, the network adapter in virtual machine settings is configured as NAT. Here’s the file at `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`:

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
#UUID=47fc2dd9-bca4-4912-95b5-7939b3e0ebf5
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
HWADDR=08:00:27:06:9c:d5
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth1"
LAST_CONNECT=1392385849
```

How do I need to configure my networking, both in the virtual machine settings and on the guest OS?

**EDIT**

ifconfig:

```
# ifconfig
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:06:9C:D5  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe06:9cd5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:90 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3731 (3.6 KiB)  TX bytes:6688 (6.5 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:720 (720.0 b)  TX bytes:720 (720.0 b)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:B9:22:2C  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Comment: @JakeGould added the output of `ifconfig`.  There is no `/etc/network/interfaces` file, and I don't know the networking setup, other than I'm running a local VM in virtual box and I'm behind a proxy.

Comment: If you are behind a proxy then that's probably your problem.